# Visual Studio 2013 Add custom toolbar Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Hey all I have been searching Google for a while now trying to find anything on how to go about setting up you're own button on the VS toolbar.

What I am talking about is this:

[image]

And when I click on that button I would like to be able to execute some C# code.

As an example, say I had the word "HELLO" highlighted and I pushed on that button on the toolbar and I wrote some code behind it that, when pressed, have whatever is highlighted turn **bold** and change color from normal **BLACK** to [image].

I was originally thinking that it was called **Visual Studio Extensibility Tools** but that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for here - it seemed more as a Nuget plugin type of thing?

I'm looking for more like what you can do with the Office suite of products within VS **addins** - As in make a button for Outlooks toolbar, etc..

[image]

The only remotely close thing I could find so far would be [this](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/index.html).

If anyone has done this before or at least know what to search for then please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with Visual Studio Extensiblilty tools.

There are several steps.

- Create the Toolbar and add the button.
- Create the event handler that runs when the button is clicked.
- Determine what document has focus   (c# doc, xml doc, vb doc, etc.)
- Determine what is selected in the document.
- Change the code formatting

Start with an overview of the [Extensions SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166030(v=vs.120).aspx).

Here's how to create a toolbar with the VS extensions.
[Creating a Toolbar for the IDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164715(v=vs.120).aspx)